# How to display two or more properties of an object in a TreeView in WPF, only one of which being the Hierarchical items?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have an observable collection of nested objects which I am displaying in a `TreeView` in WPF.

```
public class NestedContainer
{
    public FXR1.FXContainer myContainer { get; set; }
    public string XID { get { return myContainer.XID; } }
    public FXR1.FXActionData ActionData { get { return myContainer.ActionData; } }
    public FXR1.FXModifier Modifier { get { return myContainer.Modifier; } }
    public List<NestedContainer> childContainers { get; set; } = new List<NestedContainer>();
}
```

I was successful in creating the nested structure that I want, using the following XAML code it displays in a TreeView like so:

```
<TreeView x:Name="FXNodeTree" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NestedContainer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=childContainers}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=XID}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

[image: Current display example]

However, I am also trying to display the `ActionData` and `Modifier` (if any) associated with each Container, as items in the `TreeView` located just below the Container's `childContainers`. These items do not have child containers of their own, so they are just additional pieces of info belonging to each Container. My initial thought after some research was to use Multibinding and bind `ActionData` and `Modifier` in addition to `childContainers`, but I was unable to find any similar examples of this so I am unsure if this is the ideal solution. My knowledge of WPF is very entry level, so I apologize if this is a very basic problem or if I'm missing an obvious solution. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: it is unclear, if you want ActionData and Modifier to have thier own level in hierarchy or not.

Comment: You can display whatever you want in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. If you want to display something "just below" the child items, you will have to create your own custom `ControlTemplate` for the `TreeViewItem` container.

Comment: Your binding source must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` even if you don't raise the `PropertyChanged` event. Not functional relevant, but your naming convention is not consistent. Some properties use PascalCase and some camelCase. Normally camelCase is only used for field members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to display additional information of each node data.

For this purpose, you should override the default `ControlTeplate` of the `TreeViewItem`. This way you can inject a second content host below the items host (`ItemsPresenter`).
If you introduce an attached property to hold a `DataTemplate` that describes the additional content you can avoid to subclass `TreeViewItem`. This attached property can be defined on any suitable type. This example chooses the `MainWindow`.

To avoid memory leaks, the binding source must always implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or preferably implement properties as dependency properties. Even if the property values won't change.

The following example shows a fragment of the extracted `TreeViewItem` default `Style`. It misses other referenced resources in order to compact the example.
You can extract the complete Style using the XAML designer and then paste the `Style` for the `TreeViewItem` from below to replace the extracted `Style` of the `TreeViewItem`.
I have annotated the modified parts to help spotting the required modifications.

**MainWindow.xanl.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static DataTemplate GetExtendedContentItemTemplate(DependencyObject attachingElement) 
    => (DataTemplate)attachingElement.GetValue(ExtendedContentItemTemplateProperty);

  public static void SetExtendedContentItemTemplate(DependencyObject attachingElement, DataTemplate value) 
    => attachingElement.SetValue(ExtendedContentItemTemplateProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtendedContentItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "ExtendedContentItemTemplate", 
    typeof(DataTemplate), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    
    <!-- The example DataTemplate for the extended content -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ExtendedDataContentTemplate"
                  DataType="NestedContainer">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActionData}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Modifier}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- 
         The fragment of the complete TreeViewItem style.
         The first setter that sets the attached 'ExtendedContentItemTemplate' property
         and the ControlTemplate that extends the layout to add the ContentControl 
         for the additional content are of special interest here.
    -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

      <!-- Assign the DataTemplate for the extended content to the attached property -->
      <Setter Property="local:MainWindow.ExtendedContentItemTemplate"
              Value="{StaticResource ExtendedDataContentTemplate}" />

      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
              Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
              Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
      <Setter Property="Padding"
              Value="1,0,0,0" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
              Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19"
                                  Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Default header row -->
                <RowDefinition /> <!-- Default child items row -->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- New extra content row -->
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                            ClickMode="Press"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                            Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" />
              <Border x:Name="Bd"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
              </Border>
              <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              Grid.Row="1" />
    
              <!-- 
                   The host for the extra content below the child items.
                   For this purpose we have to introduce a third row to the Grid.
                   The Content is the data item itself (in this case 'NestedContainer').
                   The ContentTemplate binds to the attached property ExtendedContentItemTemplate 
                   that is set on the TreeViewItem via the current Style (see style setter above).
              --> 
              <ContentControl Grid.Row="2"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"
                              ContentTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:MainWindow.ExtendedContentItemTemplate)}" />
            </Grid>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                       Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="ItemsHost"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                       Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="Expander"
                        Value="Hidden" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                       Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        TargetName="Bd"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
              </Trigger>
              <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                             Value="true" />
                  <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive"
                             Value="false" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        TargetName="Bd"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
              </MultiTrigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                       Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing"
                 Value="true">
          <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="NestedContainer"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ChildContainers}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XID}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
  </TreeView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this answers how to accomplish the question I posed. However, through additional help and research I realize that what I was trying to do with the Tree View was not really an intended use case, and it was better to adjust my code so that I could arrange the collection which the tree was bound to to be exactly how I wanted it to display. Rather than make the Tree out of just containers, I am now making out of nodes that can either be containers, action data, or modifiers.

Comment: Well, it didn't take much time to modify the style. So don't worry. Good luck!